# how can i extract the index of subitems in a listview?

Tags: c#, listview, indexing

im trying to pass an item from a listview1 to another listview2 and i want to check if the selected item is still not present in listview2. im trying to use a for loop to get each index of listview2 and compare it to the item selected in listview1. i tried using this but an error says that value of 0 is not a valid index.

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool test = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string ls = listView2.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
        string ps = listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text;
        if (ls.Trim() == ps.Trim())
        {
            test = false;
        }
    }
    if (test == true)
    {
        ListViewItem ty = new ListViewItem(listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text);
        ty.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[1].Text);
        listView2.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { ty });
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Student is already present in the list.","Cannot add to list",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
 }
```

figured it out just as suggested. i used the foreach statement

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 bool test = true;
 string ps = listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text;           
 foreach(ListViewItem disitem in listView2.Items)
 {
  string ls = disitem.SubItems[0].Text;
  if (ps.Trim() == ls.Trim())
  {
  test = false;
  }}
  if (test == true)
  {
  ListViewItem ty = new ListViewItem(listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text);                ty.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[1].Text);
  listView2.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { ty });
  }
  else
  {
  MessageBox.Show("Student is already present in the list.","Cannot add to list",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
  }}
```

Comment: Your code does not make any sense. You are interating through the ListView1 items (with du) and applying these indices to ListView2 (which, presumably is empty). Also It is not clear why relying on the DoubleClick event (which refers to the ListView, not to an item) and then bring into account a specific item (instead of checking all of them). You should rely on a selected-item event or just inspect all the items. Please, explain what you want exactly: just moving all the items from ListView1 to ListView2? What about the selected item?

Comment: thats my problem. i dont know how to extract the indices of listview2 so that i can compare it to the selected item in listview1

Comment: i want to check the item from listview1 if it is already present in listview2.

Comment: And what has listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index] to do with all this?

Comment: Well... I guess that you have quite a few answers already, better deal with them.

Comment: thank you for helping out guys. the stackoverflow community has helped me a lot with my project

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to pass an item from a listview1 to another listview2 and I
>   want to check if the selected item is still not present in listview2.

I would simplify your method to something like:

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the value of the selected item
    string theItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

    // Add to second list if it's not already in there
    if(!listView2.Items.Contains(theItem))
    {
        listView2.Items.Add(theItem);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Student is already present in the list.","Cannot add to list",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd do the same, though was trying to follow OP logic for a bit, while simplifying things... ^^.

Comment: im comparing a subitem. contains doesnt work with string

Answer (score 1):

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool test = true;
    var selectedItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

    foreach(var item in listview2.Items)
    {
         string listview2Text = item.SubItems[0].Text;
         string listview1Text = selectedItem.SubItems[0].Text;

         if (listview2Text.Trim() == listview1Text.Trim())
         {
            test = false;
         }
    }
    if (test == true)
    {
        //I am not sure exactly what you're trying to do if the test is true but I think you're trying to do this
        listView2.Items.Add(selectedItem);
    } 
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Student is already present in the list.","Cannot add to list",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
}
```

Comment: test will be whatever the last iteration was.

Comment: @Sam Leach No the test will come out as false only if the item is present in listview2 otherwise will loop through every item of listview2 and still be true.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be something like:

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool add = true;
    string selected = listView1.Items[listView1.FocusedItem.Index];
    foreach(ListViewItem item in listView2.Items)
        if (selected.SubItems[0].Text == item.SubItems[0].Text)
        {
            add = false;
            break;
        }
    if(add)
        listView2.Items.Add(selected);
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Student is already present in the list.","Cannot add to list",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
}
```

but I am pretty unsure...